# AngularJS - Project Structure - Mixing public and private pages

Tags: angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I intend to build a typical information website that has a number of pages that do not require authorization to view them, however I also want to have a private section for staff to log in. For simplicity I am hoping I can do one Web API project and have everything within it to simplify my publishing to azure, simplify domain names and certificates etc.

Is it ok for me to have index.html as a container and use ui-router to navigate through even the public pages or would it be better to have all public pages as full html files and do typical href navigation between them?

Below is the possible structure I was thinking of

app/ -> all angularjs stuff including private views and controllers
Models/
Controllers
Index.html -> public home page
public/ all public pages

What I am trying to achieve is that all public views can be accessed via http but once the login page is accessed all traffic must from then on be https, does anyone have any experience of this?

**Update:**
I have decided to force https for all pages, does this take the structure worry away in that everything just goes under app?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to keep this is as a full Angular SPA, using ui-router to move between views instead of having static pages (even if your partial views are just plain HTML without functionality). You can affect the UX by alternating between dynamic routing with Angular and typical old href navigation. The less the you make the user reload pages, the better user experience he/she will get, plus you must be consistent in the way the application flows overall so the user doesn't have bad impressions of it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me believe I'm on the right track, I have experience of splitting things up and then having to deal with CORS which can be tricky at times even when configured correctly so I want to avoid that.

Comment: I think the issue I need most help with is having it all http until the login page and then all pages within that which need to be https, Azure gives me both http and https endpoints from what I can tell.

Comment: Yeah, that'll require some configuration with the webapi framework routing, I think there's a way to require https for certain routes (I'm not very familiar with webapi, so I'm not of big help there).

Comment: I'm guessing the following would work to switch over to https when we arrive at the login page?                                                                      var forceSSL = function () {
    if ($location.protocol() !== 'https') {
        $window.location.href = $location.absUrl().replace('http', 'https');
    }
};
forceSSL();

Comment: After further reading I have decided to have every page as https, with this I take it I now don't need to worry about the app structure, just put everything under app?

Comment: That's correct, you don't have to worry too much about it, though it's always a good practice to have a neatly ordered architecture in your applications, for maintainability and further coding purposes. (Sorry for the late responses!)

Comment: Thanks ZSnake, any help is appreciated no matter the delay :)